# Specifying the type of keyword arguments in Common Lisp methods

Tags: methods, common-lisp, dispatch, keyword-argument, clos

I thought i could define a method which accepts keyword arguments. But when i have multiple methods with keyword arguments of different types, it seems that lisp uses the last evaluated method. For example below:

```
(defmethod f (&key (x list)) (make-list 3 :initial-element (first x)))
(defmethod f (&key (x number)) (* 2 x))
```

Now `f`'s `:x` accepts only numbers and throws errors for lists:

```
(f :x 2)                ;4
```

but

```
(f :x '(2))
```

> The value (2) is not of type NUMBER when binding SB-KERNEL::X [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

How can i define multiple methods with &key args of different types?

Comment: Common Lisp does not support dispatching on keyword arguments. Thus it's not possible to declare classes for keyword arguments. See the syntax of defmethod in the Common Lisp HyperSpec: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defmet.htm#defmethod

Answer (score 4):

You can only dispatch on required positional parameters.  Any `&optional`, `&key`, `&rest` and `&aux` parameters only work as in normal lambda lists.

Because of this, your second definition did not differ in the dispatching part and overwrote the existing method.  I also believe that your example should have issued warnings about `list` and `number` being unbound variables.